# What will be executed first in Node.js/Javascript Event Loop among setInterval(()=>{}, 5000) and setTimeout(()=>{}, 5000)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, event-loop

Since both falls in the "Timers" phase of Event Loop in Javascript/Node.js -

```
let racer = function () {
  setInterval(() => { console.log('Interval is here') }, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('Timeout is here') }, 2000);
}
```

Just looking for initial order of execution of above code snippet?

Comment: All JavaScript platforms I know of honor the order of timer registration, so your interval timer would fire before the timeout.

Comment: First the `setInterval` will be executed and then the `setTimeout`. As for which *callback* will fire first, it's almost guaranteed to be the interval, then the timeout.

Comment: So just order matters in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html) does not seem to indicate any priority between the `list of active timeouts` and the `list of active intervals`.

Therefore the execution order of your `racer` function depends on browser implementation.

Comment: That's what my question was. I haven't found any concept like that. To few people it may seems like silly question but there is no actual proof or explanation given. Thanks for the clarification.